# Is this series conditionally convergent or absolutely convergent? $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}\frac{k^{k}}{\left(k+1\right)^{k+1}} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is this series conditionally convergent or absolutely convergent? How to prove it ?

I tried ratio test and root test, but did not work I think.

$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}\frac{k^{k}}{\left(k+1\right)^{k+1}}
$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a much more positive response if you show your work in the body of the question.  What have you tried so far?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Have you an asymptotic for $k^k/(k+1)^{k+1}$?

Comment: $$\frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k\,(k+1)}\ge \frac{e}{k+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

To show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}\frac{k^{k}}{\left(k+1\right)^{k+1}}$ converges, it suffices to show that $k \mapsto \frac{k^{k}}{\left(k+1\right)^{k+1}}$ is monotonically decreasing and then we can apply the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Consider $$f(x) = \ln\frac{x^x}{(x+1)^{x+1}} = x \ln x - (x+1)\ln (x+1)$$ We have $f'(x) = \ln x - \ln (x+1) < 0$ so $f$ is monotonically decreasing.

Then $e^{f(x)} = \frac{x^x}{(x+1)^{x+1}}$ is also monotonically decreasing so the claim follows.

Answer (score -1):

**Hints**

Use the alternating series test to determine whether the series is convergent. For absolute convergence use the limit comparison test, noting that
$$
\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}}\biggr/\frac{1}{k}=\lim_{k\to \infty}
\left(1-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)^{k+1}=\frac{1}{e}
$$
and compare with the harmonic series.

Comment: You meant like this $
\lim_{k\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\frac{k^{k}}{\left(k+1\right)^{k+1}}}{\frac{1}{k}}=\lim_{k\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{k}+1}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{k}+1}\right)=\frac{1}{e}
$ Therefore, it is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: But how to show is it conditionally convergent? Show $
a_{k}=\frac{k^{k}}{\left(k+1\right)^{k+1}}
$ is monotone decreasing by calculating its derivative?